# Camel useExponentialBackoff not working correctly

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I have setup a camel routing with an errorHandler and redelivery policy configured as below

```
<errorHandler id="apiRetryHandler" type="DefaultErrorHandler">
<redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="5" redeliveryDelay="30000"
backOffMultiplier="5" useExponentialBackOff="true"
useCollisionAvoidance="true"/><errorHandler>
```

I am expecting the following outcome

- Message 1 -> Actual message
- Message 2 -> 1st Retry = 30 Seconds
- Message 3 -> 2nd Retry (30 [redeliveryDelay] x 5 [backoffMultipler])
  = 2.5 mins
- Message 4 -> 3rd Retry ( 2.5 mins (previous) x 5 [backoffMultipler]) = 12.5 mins

On the first failure, when I receive an exception from the system, the handler kicks in the following order

- 1st Retry - 30 seconds
- 2nd Retry - 1 min
- 3rd Retry - 1 min
  ...
- 6th Retry - 1 min

Please advice what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a maximum redelivery delay of 60 seconds [1]. You need to set that to a higher value. Also its is not recommended to use long delay values, eg 12.5 minutes is a very long time.

```
<errorHandler id="apiRetryHandler" type="DefaultErrorHandler">
<redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveryDelay="30min" maximumRedeliveries="5" redeliveryDelay="30sec"
backOffMultiplier="5" useExponentialBackOff="true"
useCollisionAvoidance="true"/><errorHandler>
```

- [1] http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html

Comment: Why is it not recommended to use long delay values? Is it because a delay blocks a thread? and longer delays can lead to thread pool exhaustion (at least that's what I have seen in my case). If yes, then is there a non-bocking model for retry and back-off

Comment: You can set it to async retry, but not in transaction. `setAsyncDelayedRedelivery: Sets whether asynchronous delayed redelivery is allowed. This is disabled by default. When enabled it allows Camel to schedule a future task for delayed redelivery which prevents current thread from blocking while waiting. Exchange which is transacted will however 
always use synchronous delayed redelivery because the transaction must execute in the same thread context.`